# How to generate random number in while loop only once?

Tags: python, random, while-loop

I am trying to complete a Guessing game. Here's the code:

```
import random

def guess_function(x):
    while True:
        number = random.randint(0,x)
        userinput = input(f"Guess a number between 0 to {x}: ")
        if userinput.lower() == "q":
            break
        userinput =  int(userinput)
        if int(userinput) == number:
            print("Thats correct")
            continue
        if userinput < number:
            print("TOO low ")
        if userinput > number:
            print("TOO high ")

guess_function(100)
```

But the problem in this code is this generates a new random number every time I make a guess right or wrong, if I declare the number variable outside the while loop then new number wont be generated after I guess the correct number. I want this to continuously run until I press <kbd>q</kbd>. I have tried `elif` and if both, it still generates new number. Also tried to add a `while` loop inside this while loop but that makes it a infinite loop.

I want to know how can I have this continuously run and have same random number and once I make right guess the number changes but without ending game, means not having to run the code again.

Comment: You need two loops: one for guessing a generated number, and one for repeating the entire game.

Comment: @deceze OP only needs to declare the random number outside of the loop. There's no need for a second loop.

Comment: @dio True, you can do it with one loop as well, but I might go with a loop repeating the function from the outside. One function call plays one game, and that game can be repeated in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continuously generate random numbers until the user enters "q" then this can be an approach:

```
import random

def guess_function(x):
    number = random.randint(0,x)
    while number >= 0:
        userinput = input(f"Guess a number between 0 to {x}: ")
        if userinput.lower() == "q":
            number = -1
            break
        userinput = int(userinput)
        if userinput == number:
            print("Thats correct")
            number = random.randint(0,x)
            continue
        if userinput < number:
            print("TO low ")
        if userinput > number:
            print("TO high ")

guess_function(100)
```

You generate a new number after a correct guess and continue the game, once the user enters "q", the `number` variable is set to -1 and the condition for the loop fails and the function returns with game stopping completely.

Comment: This was really helpful Thank you

Comment: @codermaster69 check it again, i edited it

Answer (score -1):

**Try This:**

```
import random

def guess_function(x):
    number = random.randint(0,x)
    while True:
        userinput = input(f"Guess a number between 0 to {x}: ")
        if userinput.lower() == "q":
            break
        userinput =  int(userinput)
        if int(userinput) == number:
            print("Thats correct")
            continue
        if userinput < number:
            print("TO low ")
        if userinput > number:
            print("TO high ")

guess_function(100)
```

**#Just put it outside of the loop.**

Comment: SO isn't like GitHub, you don't need to declare the code type for colored code

Comment: Thanks, I am kind of new to it :)

Comment: If i declare it outside the while loop then it wont give me a new number once i make correct guess i want this code to keep running and as i make a right guess the random should change

Comment: @codemaster69 You could make a loop to repeatedly call the function.